# unable to display value from previous activity

Tags: android, kotlin, kotlin-android-extensions

While displaying value to a `textview` on second activity getting error as

> expecting member declaration

This is my code for Another Activity:

```
   package com.example.trial.sudoku_solver
import android.app.AlertDialog
import android.content.Intent
import android.graphics.Bitmap
import android.media.MediaScannerConnection
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity
import android.os.Bundle
import android.os.Environment
import android.provider.MediaStore
import android.text.Editable
import android.util.Log
import android.view.View
import android.widget.*
import com.example.trial.sudoku_solver.R
import kotlinx.android.synthetic.main.activity_main.view.*
import java.io.ByteArrayOutputStream
import java.io.File
import java.io.FileOutputStream
import java.io.IOException
import java.util.*
import kotlinx.android.synthetic.main.activity_main.*
import org.w3c.dom.Text

class AnotherActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_another)
    }


    var a: String = intent.getStringExtra("text")
    val text1: TextView = findViewById(R.id.textview) as TextView
    text1.text = intent.getStringExtra("text")

}
```

This is my partial code for the function in MainActivity

```
private fun clickText() {
    val text1: EditText = findViewById(R.id.editText)
    if (text1 != null) {
        //Toast.makeText(this, text1.text, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
        var text1 = text1.editText.toString()
        val intent = Intent(this, AnotherActivity::class.java)
        intent.putExtra("text",text1)
        startActivity(intent);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

8You need to call `intent`, `findViewById` and then `setText` after the call to `setContentView`:

```
class AnotherActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_another)

        var a: String = intent.getStringExtra("text")
        val text1: TextView = findViewById(R.id.textview) as TextView
        text1.text = intent.getStringExtra("text")
    }
}
```

Comment: I am getting output as :

Comment: sorry output as what?

Comment: Instead of the text typed on previous activity I am getting output as :"android.support.v7.widget.AppCombatEditText{6a2a25bVEFD..CL. .F...... 0,0-720,84 #7f070036.app:id/editText}"

Comment: Then you're passing the wrong value from the first activity, the problem is not in `AnotherActivity`

Comment: @BalaKumar Wild guess, you should do `intent.putExtra("text", editText.text.toString)` instead of  `intent.putExtra("text", editText.toString)`, notice the `.text`

Answer (score 0):

Threre is no settext method in an `Activity`. You should set the text string to `TextView` like that:

```
var a: String = intent.getStringExtra("text")
val text1 = findViewById(R.id.textview) as TextView
text1.text = a
```

In addition, when you write code in kotlin, it is not necessary to use findViewById in activities. Because of synthetic properties, the views are accessible via their ids from xml file. So, your three line of code could be replaced as below:

```
textview.text = intent.getStringExtra("text")
```

Also change the code block in MainActivity to:

```
private fun clickText() {
    val editText1: EditText = findViewById(R.id.editText)
    if (editText1 != null) {
        //Toast.makeText(this, text1.text, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
        var text1 = editText1.text.toString()
        val intent = Intent(this, AnotherActivity::class.java)
        intent.putExtra("text", text1)
        startActivity(intent);
    }
}
```

Comment: I think if you remove this line "import kotlinx.android.synthetic.main.activity_main.view.*" it's gonna be ok.

Comment: Instead of the text typed on previous activity I am getting output as :"android.support.v7.widget.AppCombatEditText{6a2a25bVEFD..CL. .F...... 0,0-720,84 #7f070036.app:id/editText}"

Comment: @BalaKumar: see above snippet in answer.

Comment: @aminography great explanation **your answer is perfect for the  question**
in kotlin no need binding any elements instated of that just  import  this **_import kotlinx.android.synthetic.main.activity_main.view_** OR for setText()/getText() use only .text.

**BalaKumar** i think its perfect answer for your question.
still you face issue just debug the code and check data is travel from on activity another activity.

Happy Learning...

Comment: @Arbaz.in perfect answer what, the problem is that you have to execute the statement `text1.text = intent.getStringExtra("text")` within a method, the OP did it as if it was a class member declaration, I solved the problem in my answer and also another speculative issue the OP had. Have you at least read before commenting?

Answer (score 0):

> The easiest way to do this :

```
Intent intent = new Intent(getBaseContext(), Activity2.class);
intent.putExtra("ID", sId);
startActivity(intent);
```

> Access that intent on next activity

```
String sId= getIntent().getStringExtra("ID");
```

Hope this will help you

Comment: This comment is in java though. I'm using kotlin

Answer (score 0):

You need to add these piece of code inside onCreate method block

You should add your executable statements inside methods.

So the code will look like this:

```
 override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_another)

        // add these statement inside onCreate block
        var a: String = intent.getStringExtra("text")
        val text1: TextView = findViewById(R.id.textview) as TextView
        text1.text = intent.getStringExtra("text")
    }
```